How to connect external GCP project with Google Billing Account?
I am new to GCP
I am trying to connect Google Project to other Billing Account
For example if i have Google map project in my account then i want to connect this map project with billing account which on another login.
How can i do that?
Is that possible?
I have tried but stuck on creating IAM and json file on billing account
below is the code i am using
<?php
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

use Google\Auth\Credentials\GceCredentials;
use Google\Client;
use Google\Service\Cloudbilling;

function linkBillingAccount($projectId, $billingAccountName) {
    $client = new Client();
    $client->setApplicationName('Google Cloud Billing API PHP Quickstart');
    $client->useApplicationDefaultCredentials();
    $client->addScope(Google\Service\Cloudbilling::CLOUD_BILLING);

    $billingService = new Cloudbilling($client);

    $billingProjectName = "projects/{$projectId}/billingInfo";

    $billingInfo = new Cloudbilling\ProjectBillingInfo([
        'billingAccountName' => $billingAccountName
    ]);

    try {
        $response = $billingService->projects->updateBillingInfo($billingProjectName, $billingInfo);
        printf("Project %s is now linked to billing account %s\n", $projectId, $response->getBillingAccountName());
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo 'Error: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
}

// Replace with your project ID and billing account ID
$projectId = 'your-project-id';
$billingAccountName = 'billingAccounts/your-billing-account-id';

linkBillingAccount($projectId, $billingAccountName);
?>

I don't know what settings i need to update on both google account
Need little guidance on linking billing account and external GCP project via php api
